# Proving that $\varnothing$ is in an algebra of subsets of $X$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

This is based on Yeh's *Real Analysis: Theory of Measure and Integration*, 3rd ed.

> **Definition 1.1**. Let $X$ be an arbitrary set. A collection $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $X$ is called an algebra of subsets of $X$ if it satisfies the following conditions:
>
> $1^{\circ}\text{ }X \in \mathcal{A}$
>
> $2^{\circ}\text{ }A \in \mathcal{A} \implies A^c \in \mathcal{A}$
>
> $3^{\circ}\text{ }A, B \in \mathcal{A} \implies A \cup B \in \mathcal{A}$
>
> **Lemma 1.2.1**. If $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of subsets of a set $X$, then $\varnothing \in \mathcal{A}$.

Yeh says that this lemma follows from $1^{\circ}$ and $2^{\circ}$ above. The only way I can see this working is if $X$ is a universal set satisfying $X^{c} = \varnothing$. Is this correct, or am I missing the point?

Also, this makes me wonder if complements are actually supposed to be relative to $X$ (although I can't find this stated in the textbook) - i.e., for any $A \in \mathcal{A}$, $A^c = X \setminus A$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

Working in universe $X$ it is *by definition* that $A^{\complement}=X-A$ (hence $X^{\complement}=\varnothing$).

We only work with *complements* if there is an obvious universal set.